# Firoozbakht’s conjecture and Cramér's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Firoozbakht’s conjecture asserts that, for every prime number:
$$\sqrt[{k+1}]{p_{k+1}}\lt\sqrt[{k}]{p_k} \ \ \forall k\ge 1$$
Cramer's conjecture asserts that:
$$p_{n+1}-p_n=O(\log p_n)^2$$
Firoozbakht’s conjecture is believed to be false, as it contradicts the Cramer's one. Why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would write out an inequality using the definition of the $O$ notation being employed in Cramer's conjecture, from there I would manipulate that inequality until I could get something similar to the first conjecture, in hopes I would encounter said contradiction.

Comment: Gerry Myerson's answer below indicates that it's not Cramer's conjecture that it contradicts (it seems that, in fact, it implies it), but rather the Cramer-Granville heuristic.

Comment: While I agree with the answer above, I wanted to point out a Firoozbakht’s conjecture correction.
$\sqrt[{p_{k+1}}]{p_{k+1}}\lt\sqrt[{p_k}]{p_k}$
Should be
$\sqrt[{k+1}]{p_{k+1}}\lt\sqrt[{k}]{p_{k}}$, or it should be $p_k^{1/k} > p_{k+1}^{1/{(k+1)}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying my answer to [Ratio of logarithmic primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320801/ratio-of-logarithmic-primes);

This is [Firoozbakht’s conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%E2%80%99s_conjecture). According to the link, it has been verified for primes up to $4\times10^{18}$, but is believed to be false, as it contradicts the [Cramér–Granville heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Cram.C3.A9r.E2.80.93Granville_conjecture).

Added: there is also some discussion which may be useful at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90327/any-progress-on-the-firoozbakht-conjecture

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93643/an-empirical-observation-on-a-limit-involving-consecutive-primes/93663

Comment: Why do we believe that it is Firoozbakht's conjecture that should be false and not Cramer-Granville's heuristics ?

Comment: @Sylvain Julien - Different authors believe different things; e.g. the authors of arXiv:1604.03496 believe Firoozbakht's conjecture is true. The author of arXiv:1208.2683 believes that there are at most finitely many violations of Firoozbakht's conjecture (see Conj. 2.3 in arXiv:1208.2683); that is, Firoozbakht's conjecture is true for large enough primes.

Comment: Yet another distinct possibility is that BOTH Firoozbakht's conjecture and Cramer-Granville's heuristics are false.

Comment: Another source of information on the relation between Firoozbakht and prime gaps is Alexei Kourbatov, Upper bounds for prime gaps related to Firoozbakht's conjecture, J Integer Sequences 18 (2015) 15.11.2, available at https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL18/Kourbatov/kourb7.pdf